# HTML W3C Valid Elements - Is DIV valid within a TD?

Tags: html

I'm having an argument with a colleague, but can't find the evidence to prove either of us right. I've seen the list of valid elements for given tags before, but just cant find it again. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

I am curious about XHTML, but the disagreement is specifically over whether a DIV tag is valid within a TD tag in HTML 4.01.

Comment: Throw together a test HTML file with a `<div>` inside a `<td>`, paste the code into http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and find out.

Comment: Thanks folks, both very helpful! If its OK Ill give you both 'helpful' uparrows and the 'answered' tick to the newer guy as I know its harder when you first start out. :)

Comment: @cmrn No problem! ;) But to be fair, you both answered my question!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. According to the HTML 4.01 DTD, a `td` element can contain block-level elements and/or inline-level elements.

Relevant line of the DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT (TH|TD)  - O (%flow;)*       -- table header cell, table data cell-->
```

This line basically defines the `th` and `td` elements, and states that they may contain any combination (`*`) of block and inline elements (`%flow;`).

More info on `td`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TD

Answer (score 5):

Yes, `div` within `td` is perfectly valid. The [elements list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1) in the HTML5 spec draft is a useful reference for this sort of question, but basically, the valid children of [`td`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-td-element) are *flow* elements, and [`div`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-div-element) is a flow element.

The above references are for HTML5, which is the way forward (it both codifies what's already in the wild, and brings things forward; the major browser vendors are all involved). For HTML 4.01, the TD reerence is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-TD), but I have to admit for 4.01 what I'd probably do is ask the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/), which is quite robust for 4.01 (and not yet for HTML5). And the validator says...yup, just fine. Sample data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head><title>Hi</title></head>
<body>
<table><tbody><tr><td><div>x</div></td></tr></tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Gumbo: I totally missed that, I'll find the HTML 4.01 references, but HTML5 is the way forward in any case.

Comment: Updated. Answer is still: Yes, it's fine.

Comment: HTML 5 is an unstable draft containing large chunks of stuff that is impractical to use on the web today. It is worth keeping an eye on, but not rushing into. HTML 4.01 is still the best choice for most developers.

Comment: @David: Parts of it are certainly unstable (even wildly unstable), but the majority of the *basics* (like which of the old elements can be inside which other old elements) have been reviewed and updated. I wouldn't start using `section` and such yet (not least because it won't work correctly on IE without JavaScript), but for the basics, it's now my default reference point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can place a div in a td. I do it all the times.