# Rotate image in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am experimenting with an image fader rotater which I found on jsFiddle. I am having problems containing the images within a table, as the image always overlaps the table borders. Is there a way to ensure the table height is the same height as the images (my table is defined using percentages). Here is the code:

```js
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
    .next('img')
    .fadeIn()
    .end()
    .appendTo('.fadein');
}, 4000); // 4 seconds
```

```css
.fader {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%px;
}
.fadein {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width=100% class="fader">
  <tr>
    <td width="70%">
      <div class="fadein">

        <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8359/8450229021_9d660578b4_n.jpg">
        <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8510/8452880627_0e673b24d8_n.jpg">
        <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8108/8456552856_a843b7a5e1_n.jpg">
        <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8230/8457936603_f2c8f48691_n.jpg">
        <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8329/8447290659_02c4765928_n.jpg">

      </div>
    </td>
    <td>testing 123</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think you can actually nest a `div` inside a table cell. Also, close your image tags by ending with `/>`. Your cells should scale automatically when you insert images into them. Also, why is your css `width: 100%px`, and also, if you determine the `div`s `width` and `height`, it might not scale properly anyhow as it has values that are determined by the cellsize, not the images inside it.

Comment: I have just turned your code into a snippet and when you run it, it seems to work as desired. What is the problem? What issue are you seeing?

Comment: @somethinghere Yes, you CAN put a <code>div</code> inside a <code>td</code> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117454/html-w3c-valid-elements-is-div-valid-within-a-td

Comment: @squaleLis Yes you can, you can nest anything in anything, but that was far from my only point. Good point, but that wasn't my main gripe at all.

Comment: @somethinghere: I don't get your point. (1) You can actually nest a `div` inside a table cell. [(Ref)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/td.html) says permitted content is flow.content and [(as per this)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.flow) `div` is flow content. (2) There is no need to close the image tags. [(See here)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23739417/1355315).

Comment: @Abhitalks 'There is not need to close image tags' - what? Are we back in 1999? Come on, basics. Yes _there is no **need**_, everything will work the same, but it's simply accepted standards and semantics, which is never bad to agree upon. I have _agreed_ to the first point thanks to the  SO article posted, so I don't get _your_ point of bringing it up again.

Comment: @somethinghere: (1) "*..it's simply accepted standards..*" -- yes, the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element) says that closing is not required. (2) I *accept* that I didn't read your comment above before posting mine. That was indeed *my* mistake bringing it up again.

Comment: @Abhitalks You know what? Whatever. There seems to be this fixation on the parts that were _suggestions and thoughts_ and not the parts that refer to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue may be coming from the fact that for a small amount of time, 2 of the images show up at the same time causing overlapping issues.

If you add some `delay()` to your function then it should sort your issue out.

```js
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

setInterval(function() {
  $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut('500').next().delay('400').fadeIn('500').end().appendTo('.fadein');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.fadein :first-child').css('display', 'block');
  }, 400);
}, 4000);
```

```css
.fader {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.fadein {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
.fadein img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" width=100% class="fader">
  <tr>
    <td width="70%" class="fadein">

      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8359/8450229021_9d660578b4_n.jpg">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8510/8452880627_0e673b24d8_n.jpg">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8108/8456552856_a843b7a5e1_n.jpg">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8230/8457936603_f2c8f48691_n.jpg">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8329/8447290659_02c4765928_n.jpg">

    </td>
    <td>testing 123</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for that, seems to have helped the problem. The only issue is now is there is a slight gap between the pictures and the bottom border of the table. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @DanW see my amended answer now. Its because `fadeIn()` makes the item become `inline` rather than the required `block`. A little additional bit of code and it should work as expected :)